# Does time exist without Gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, event-horizon, observers

If you travel the universe and move into an area where there is negligible gravitational influence, does time stop? As an observer, would this be like watching someone cross the event horizon of a black hole?

Comment: Perhaps what you really wanted to ask was if time could exist without matter. The answer then would be no. Time and energy are Fourier conjugates (two sides of the same coin) and cannot exist without each other. So conceptually, regions may exist in the universe with neither matter nor time as described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040/metric-of-spacetime-with-zero-speed-of-light - Nothing from outside can cross into such a region, because the speed of light there is zero.

Comment: Thank you. That is more to the attempted point.

Comment: This is more philosophy than physics. What do you mean by "exist"? Is time an actual "thing" or just a concept we use to order events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well gravity according to Einstein's relativity theory is nothing but bending of 3D space and time called space time and this bending is caused by matter for reasons we don't know for sure. Well by no gravity you mean there's no matter in that part of space-time to bend it! So even though there's no gravity over there but space- time exists . Hence the answer to your question is, time exists even though their might be no gravity ( which is not possible since gravity is a long range force  and extends for infinite distance ) since space still exists !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, time exists without gravity!

In the Minkowski spacetime of Special Relativity there is time but no gravity. Did you learn about Lorentz transformations and kinematic time dilation? They have nothing to do with gravity.

Quantum field theories like QED and the whole Standard Model are typically formulated in flat spacetime and thus with no gravity. For example, a scattering process between two electrons occurs in time and has nothing to do with gravity.

Comment: I'm a little unconvinced. Observables only exist to the extent that we can measure them. To measure time, we need a clock, and a clock will necessarily have some mass-energy and therefore gravitate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the opposite - when there is no gravity, the difference in time observers measure only depends on their relative velocity. It's when gravity gets very strong that you can get things like an event horizon. In the case of a black hole, the time coordinate of the faraway observer "stops" at the event horizon.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> If you travel the universe and move into an area where there is no gravitational influence

No such area exists. All places in a universe experiences greater or smaller gravitational field. Body gravitational potential energy is defined as :
$$ U=-G{\frac {mM}{R}} $$
When $R \to \infty$, $U \to 0$. So you need to move at **infinite** distance from **ALL** masses in a universe for not experiencing any effects of gravitational fields. Thus, this is totally impossible. Besides even then, you have your own mass (observer mass). Your mass will self-interact in own gravitational field too.
For example your head is gravitationaly attracted to your feets and etc. This effect is miserable, however it's not zero. Thus even in principle it's impossible to avoid any gravitational fields.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: In physics you often need abstraction, whether such an area exists or not in the real universe is not necessarily that important, you could just imagine a universe with no matter, we do it all the time as an approximation!

Comment: Well, maybe **you** can imagine, but **I** can't. If there would be no matter and energy in a universe, then there would be no _Big Bang_ at all. For what reason it will explode then ? We have Big Bang, only because it started from a high-energy and high-temperature compact quantum soup. Remove this soup, and the universe will not start to expand at all. So you can't imagine everything in Physics, because you are bounded to some conditions. Not every imagination has meaning.